# A function that take another function as parameter, "No matching function error" C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters

I'm writing a series of sorting algorithm and calculating the time execution of each algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>


#include "sort.h"


template<class T>
void timeTaken(void (*f)(std::vector<T>& nums))
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    double duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

    std::cout << duration << " microseconds";
    
   // return duration;
}



template<typename T>
void display(std::vector<T>& nums)
{
    for(int x : nums) std::cout << x << "  ";
    std::cout << "\n\t ---------------------------------- \n";
}

void displayTesting()
{
    std::cout << "testing .... \n";
}

int main()
{
   
    std::vector<int> A {4,5,2,7,1,10,15};
    
    std::cout << "ORIGNAL ARRAY: ";
    
    display(A);
    
    

    bubbleSort(A);
    timeTaken(&display);        //ERROR: No matching function for call "time Taken"
    std::cout << "BUBBLE SORT: ";
    display(A);
              
  
    


    
    
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to take displayTesting() as a parameter to timeTaken(), it works fine(of course I remove the parameter after(*f) ). So i think the problem is basically how do I take a parameter of some function to take that in to timeTaken() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display` is a template; template parameter `T` can't be deduced in `timeTaken(&display);`.

You can specify the instantiation by `static_cast`,

```
timeTaken(static_cast<void (*)(std::vector<int>&)>(&display));
```

Or

```
timeTaken(&display<int>);
```

Or specify template argument explicitly.

```
timeTaken<int>(&display);
```

---

Other issues:

1. There's no `bubbleSort`.
2. `f();` is trying to call `f` without arguments, but it's supposed to accept `std::vector<T>&`.

Comment: Fixing that, there is still a problem inside of `timeTaken()` - `f` is a pointer to a function that takes a `vector` as a parameter, but `timeTaken()` is trying to call `f()` without passing a `vector` to it.

Comment: So there's an error occurs in timeTaken(), when f() has no argument. the f() won't take any vector<T>& argument

Comment: @FloydVu0531 Maybe you want this? https://wandbox.org/permlink/1hEva3Mc6ihJtDsp

Comment: `bubbleSort` is just a function that I'm trying to put in the timeTaken()